# Xamarin Forms app getting stuck on SplashScreen

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have a class SplashScreen where I show an image scaling and after it finishes scaling it goes to a login page. I tried this on multiple devices and only in one device it doesn't change from the SplashScreen.

I've been researching how to handle async methods and await instructions but nothing seems to work so far. Also I tried removing the ScaleTo and just show the image but it doesn't work.

This is what I have:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
     base.OnAppearing();
     await splashLogo.ScaleTo(1.5, 3000);
     ShowLogin();
}
```

Comment: If I had problem on just one Android device I would be happy with the result unless it is some really major model. It is still legitimate to ask how to fix that, but that requires testing on the particular device and access to whole your code. So I recommend this question for closing, though if you provide some code needed to reproduce the issue and the device info maybe someone can test and answer...

Comment: If you are testing an iOS application, I would recommend watching the iOS message in the XCode console. After you connect your iPad to your Mac via dock cable, you can start XCode and go to Window -> Devices and Simulators. The window that pops up allows you to open the device logs and start the Console application. The Console application shows debugging information that are being streamed from the device in real-time.

Comment: @IvanIčin It only happens with the S10 and I can't really provide access to the code because of privacy policies of my employer. I knew it was a long shot to ask something like this without any context.

Comment: @testingandtesting, I find this article about using slpashscreen, I try this sample and I have no issue, you can take a look:https://xamaringuyhome.blogspot.com/2017/10/xamarin-forms-welcomescreen-fading.html

Comment: @CherryBu That's the exact same code I have for the SplashScreen, but it doesn't go to `Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());`. It works fine in all devices I've tested, the problem it's just with the S10

Comment: @testingandtesting maybe plug the device in and take a look at the device log as the app starts, there might be clue in there. https://xamarininsider.com/2017/07/18/discovering-the-android-device-log/

Comment: @NigelFerrissey I tried that but I'm not really sure how to interpret the info it's giving me. I couldn't find anything with the keyword Error or Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding this class:

```
class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private bool isLoadingData;

    public bool IsLoadingData
    {
        get => isLoadingData;
        set => SetProperty(ref isLoadingData, value);
    }

    public async Task LoadData()
    {
        IsLoadingData = true;
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        IsLoadingData = false;
    }
}
```

Then in my SplashScreen page:

```
public SplashScreen()
{
    //Everything else I need in this page
    BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
}

private MainPageViewModel ViewModel => BindingContext as MainPageViewModel;

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await ViewModel.LoadData();
    ShowLogin();
}
```